# SSL on Home page of site

Tags: tomcat, caching, https, struts2

I have home page which is enough heavy with static content like images, css, js which work on making it look good and are must.

Also the page has login form, so for security I had to make home page to load using https.

**1. Will this load all the static content every time the page gets loaded?**

**2. How do I make sure that static content is cached, even if I have home page secure?**

I am using struts2, tomcat for development.